# Law of a random variable and an indicator function from a textbook

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Below is a clip from a chapter associated with conditioning in a probability textbook. Could someone kindly help to elaborate on the highlighted part regarding the law of the random variable $Y$ and the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{\{B\}}$? I am not sure why the second item on the right-hand side is expressed as the product of $P(B^c)$ and point mass $\delta_0$ .

[image]

As far as I can understand, the expression $\mathcal{L}(Y\mathbb{1}_{\{B\}})=\mathcal{L}(Y|B)P(B)$ seems more natural to me from an undergraduate level perspective. (Also what is the definition of $\delta_0$?)

The point mass $\delta_c$ is defined in other part of the book as follows.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal L (Y1_B) (A)=P(Y1_B \in A)=P(B \cap (Y \in A)) +P(B^{c} \cap (0 \in A))$. Noe $(0 \in A)$ has probabiltiy $0$ or $1$ depending on whether $0$ belongs to $A$ or not. So we get $\mathcal L (Y1_B) (A)=P(B \cap (Y \in A)) +P(B^{c}) \cap \delta_0 (A)$. according to the defintion of point mass $\delta_0$. Finally, we have $\mathcal L (Y1_B) (A)=P(B) \mathcal L(Y|B)( A)) +P(B^{c}) \cap \delta_0 (A)$.

You may note that the formula you suggested, namely, $\mathcal L (Y1_B) (A)=P(B) \mathcal L(Y|B)( A))$ fails when $A=\{0\}$.

Comment: Very helpful explanation. Thx